# install DevExpress DXperience only with one version of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, dxperience

I have Visual studio 2008 and Visual studio 2012 installed on my computer, and I want to install `DevExpress DXperience 12.1.4` but only with Visual studio 2008.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

No way.  Installer will install the DXperience under all VS instances found.

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to install DevExpress DXperience 12.1.4 but only with Visual studio 2008.
```

No, Installer will install the DXperience controls in all version of Visual studio.

But you can remove all the controls from one by [resetting the development environment setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx) from Visual Studio 2012.

> On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.
>
> On the Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click
>   Reset all settings and then click Next.

Now controls shown in the tool bar disappear from Visual Studio 2012. If you want to use them then use the toolBax creator of devexpress to get them back in all visual studio instances.

Ref:   [Reset IDE settings in Visual Studio](http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/reset-ide-settings-in-visual-studio-2008/)

Hope this is what you require.